# How do you make a hidden text field in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I would like to pass a parameter in with a form and want to have it stored in a hidden field in the template.  How is this done in emberjs?  I see from the docs [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html) that you can do this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}
```

But how to make a hidden one?  Or is a hidden textfield something that should not be handled on the front end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the input view helper, and provide the type of the field:

`{{input type="hidden" valueBinding="firstName"}}`

The `input` helper is a shortcut to `{{view Ember.TextField ...}}`, so using:

`{{view Ember.TextField type="hidden" valueBinding="firstName"}}`

is the same.